# How can I make the taxonomy terms appear in a drop down list?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

How to make the taxonomy term in drop down list?

Vocabul

Drupal 6 taxonomy term in drop down list while creating new article.
[image]

Drupal 8 taxonomy term can't show drop down list while creating new article.
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @Bhuvana

I had just changed the setting, it's work.

***Home > Administration > Structure > Content types > Technology***

[image]